# Conditional expectation multivariate distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, conditional-expectation

Let $\pmatrix{X\\Y\\Z} \sim \mathcal N\left(\pmatrix{0\\0\\0},\pmatrix{1&\rho_{12}&\rho_{13}\\\rho_{12} & 1 & \rho_{23}\\\rho_{13}&\rho_{23}&1}\right)$.

Compute $E[XY|Z]$.

I have no idea how to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using the definition of conditional expectation? Integrate with respect to the conditional distribution. The latter depends solely on the joint distribution, which is known...

Comment: $(X,Y)$ given $Z$ has a bivariate normal distribution.